# Math.Round produces different results depending on where it is run

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following line of code that is producing 2 different results.

Given the following line

```
var rounded = Math.Round(415 * 0.01f, 1);
```

I would expect this to round to 4.2 all the time.  When I run this from a console application I always get the expected result 4.2.  If I put the same line in a unit test and run that test I end up with 4.1.  I also end up with 4.1 if the line is running in a windows service.

Any thoughts as to why it would produce a different value or how to make it behave consistently?

Running this with visual studio 2013 on a 64 bit machine with .NET 4.5.

Comment: Not a clue. It appears that this call redirects to an extern though, may have something to do with it.

Comment: When rounding midpoint values, the rounding algorithm performs an equality test. Because of problems of binary representation and precision in the floating-point format, the value returned by the method can be unexpected. For more information, see Rounding and precision. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx#Precision

Comment: When I try the code in a console application, I get `4.1`. I think that the problem is that you expect the result from the calculation to be *exactly* `4.15`, which it isn't. It's `4.14999990724027` because `0.01f` isn't exactly `0.01` but `0.00999999977648258`. If you use `Math.Round(4.15, 1)` you will get `4.2`.

Comment: jesus comment looks good, another thing to note is I tried this with a fixed point value (0.01m) and was getting 4.2 as expected instead of 4.1 .

Comment: @iliketocode Decimals are accurate. Use them if you must.

Comment: To explain how the value was different on different runs, did you have the debugger attached during any one? Different configurations, Release vs Debug or AnyCpu (with or without Prefer x86) or a specific arch?

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I had similar issue. Some time after start my app computed double values with one precision and after some time - with another precision. This was extremely strange.

After some time I figured out that at some point app initializes DirectX with default flags and the DX in turn changes FPU precision with double values.

So, as an advice, please check your adjacent code for side effects.
(check DirectX usage, check external unmanaged DLLs usage)

PS: There is no magic. Do not be confused. And try to deffer Decimal usage. This is the slowest thing over OLE...

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the console and test runner use different preferred ways to round.

This should give you the same result:

```
var rounded = Math.Round(415 * 0.01f, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var rounded = Math.Round(415 * 0.01d, 1);
```

you can use double to replace float

Accuracy is not enough

Comment: doubles are floating point values too - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx